# Chrome: "В результате утечки данных на одном из сайтов или в одном из приложений..."

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome

Из фронтенда на `js` посылаю данные на бэкенд на `php`:

```js
async registerAsync(login: string, password: string): Promise<void> {
    const resp = await fetch(`php-api/users/register?lg=${login}&ps=${password}`)

    if (resp.status > 400) {
      switch (resp.status) {
        case 504: throw new Error("DB is offline")
        default: throw new Error(resp.statusText)
      }
    }

    localStorage.setItem("user", login)
  }
```

На бэкенде успешно принимаю параметры (причем, пробовал и через `POST` запрос):

```php
//// GET: api/register?lg=...&ps=...
  public function RegisterAction() {
    try {
      $login = $this->requestParams["lg"];
      $password = $this->requestParams["ps"];

      $result = $this->repo->Register($login, $password);
      return $this->response("OK");
    } catch (Throwable $th) {
      return $this->response($th->getMessage());
    }
  }
```

В ответ `php` контроллер шлет код `200` и сообщение `OK`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу избавиться от сообщения, что якобы мой пароль для этого сайта раскрыт в Google Chrome:
Причем, даже если я в Firefox выполню эту процедуру регистрации и потом в Chrome попробую зайти под этими данными, сообщение появляется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно, сайт использует протокол http.

Comment: Voprositel, да, скорее всего там не https. Без перехода на https эта проблема не решается?

Comment: Не должна, но можно попробовать хранить на клиенте захешированные пароль и логин.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это новый механизм Chrome, который сравнивает хэши паролей и, если есть совпадения с базой компрометированных, предупреждает об этом.
Разумеется, простые пароли в процессе разарботки неизбежны. Они также содержатся в той базе. Поэтому Chrome об этом постоянно предупреждает.
При использовании более сложных паролей окно не появляется.
Подробней [тут](https://security.googleblog.com/2019/12/better-password-protections-in-chrome.html).